# Admin panel not working after running setup:upgrade for custom module installation

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4

My admin panel is not working anymore after installing a custom module. Now the admin needs to load for a long time, and after it has loaded the left menu is not working: the submenu cannot be opened.

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I assume you didn't generated classes, and deploy static view files after running `setup:upgrade`. If so, try to update generated classes, and deploy static view files to see if that resolves your issue. To do that, run the following commands from your Magento root directory:

```
rm -rf generated
bin/magento setup:di:compile
rm -r pub/static/*/* var/view_preprocessed/*
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

If that does not resolve your issue, the custom module has issues, you should uninstall it. To do that, take the following steps:

Assume that module has the vendor name is **Vendor** and the module name is **Module**.

1. Remove the module directory from `app/code/Vendor`, in this example you should remove `app/code/Vendor/Module` directory.
2. Run the following commands:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

3. (Optional) If that module created database tables or columns you should drop them from your database. You can check `<custom module directory>/etc/db_schema.xml` file and `<custom module directory>/Setup` directory to know database information related to that module.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the error. My php.ini memory_limit was reset to 256M.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share some screenshots or more details so that I can help you?

These are a few things you should check first:

```
- Module Directory Path
```

Run these Commands

```
bin/magento s:up
bin/magento s:di:c
bin/magento c:f
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Another main thing you should please check if there is any **acl** apply on this

Answer (score 0):

Did you run all these commands?

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Please recheck the admin after running the above commands.
If it's not working, please recheck it after removing your custom module.
You have to run the above commands after removing your custom module.
If it works, you should update the custom module.

I don't know what you did in your custom module so I can't fix your module issue.

Comment: Yes, several times, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I found the error. My php.ini memory_limit was reset to 256M. I set it back to -1. Now it works. Again thx to all for your help.

Christian

Comment: Please mark your answer as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.